# How to maintain same session in two different sites

Tags: c#, sql-server, session, cross-domain

let suppose i have two domains

**1. abc.com

 2. xyz.com**

now the thing i want to do that i have a index page on both sites and there is a image on both index page , but when i click next in `abc.com` and image changes on `abc.com` at the same time i made a session variable in sql server . Now leave `abc.com` and come to `xyz.com`
the index page of `xyz.com` automatically gets refresh by ajax function after 2 second , now when page get refresh it will make a request to server and pick the next image name from session which we stored using `abc.com` and by getting the we will show the latest image on `xyz.com` .... Note . both sites are using the same server

can i do this ? . If yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share sessions between sites using SQL server as the session manager, I did it following these instructions, works well.

these steps are taken from: [Share ASP.net session between domains](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETShareSessionBetween-021daa39)

> ASP.NET APPLICATION : CSASPNETShareSessionBetweenSubDomains Project
>   Overview
>
> Summary:
>
> Session can be set to different modes (InProc, SqlServer, and
>   StateServer). When using SqlServer/SateServer mode, Session will store
>   in a specific  SQL Server/Sate Server. If two ASP.NET Web Applications
>   specify the same SQL Server as Session Server, all Sessions store in
>   the same database. All in all, if using  SQL Server Session, it is
>   possible to share Session between different ASP.NET  Applications.
>   Since ASP.NET stores Session Id to cookie to specify current Session,
>   so in order to share Session, it is necessary to share Session Id in
>   the cookie.
>
> The CSASPNETShareSessionBetweenSubDomains sample demonstrates how to
>   configure  a SessionState Server and then create a SharedSessionModule
>   module to achieve  sharing Session between sub domain ASP.NET Web
>   Applications.
>
> Two ASP.NET Web Applications need to run in the same Root Domain (can
>   use  different ports). Steps:
>
> 1. Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State.
>
>    Run "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe
>      -S localhost\sqlexpress -E -ssadd"   to add Session State support to Sql Server Express [1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETShareSessionBetween-021daa39).
>
>    If you haven't added Session State to SQL Server, when you configure
>      a web site to use SQL Server Mode   Session State,
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException will be thrown saying    "Invalid
>      object name 'tempdb.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'."
> 2. Configure ASP.NET Web Applications to Use SQL Server to Store Session and    Use specific decryptionKey and validationKey.
>
>    Add this settings to web.config file to use SQL Server Session
>      State:
>
>    Add this settings to web.config to use specific decryptionKey and
>      validationKey:
>
>    If you host the applications in IIS, please run the Application Pool
>      under    an account who can log into the database. Otherwise
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   will be thrown saying "Cannot
>      open database 'ASPState' requested by the login. The login failed."
> 3. Write SharedSessionModule Module to Achieve The Logic of Sharing Session
>
>    a. Implement Init() method to set Application Id read from
>      web.config.
>
>    b. Implement PostRequestHandlerExecute Event to store Session Id to
>      cookie with 
>       the same domain and root path.
> 4. Configure ASP.NET Web Applications to Use SharedSessionModule Module.
>       Add this config to web.config to use SharedSessionModule Module:
>
>    If you run the applications in your own domains except localhost,
>      please don't forget to change the value of RootDomain after
>      publishing.
> 5. Run and Test
>       a. Add a new Web Page.   b. Add two Buttons (used to Refresh the page and Set Session) and one Label for displaying
>       Session value.   c. On Page_PreRender() method, read Session and display it in Label. On Button Click
>       Event, Set Value to Session.   d. Create a new Web Site with the same config as Web Site 1, but set different value
>       to Session   e. Now open two sites in two tabs. Now if you set Session Value in site1,
>       you can retrieve the same value in site2. So they use the same Session.
>
> [1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETShareSessionBetween-021daa39) Remove Session State from Sql Server.    Run
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -S
>   localhost\sqlexpress -E -ssremove"    to remove Session State support
>   from Sql Server.